# Where can I find source code for the Linux implementation of UDP?

Tags: linux, udp

Where can I find the source code to the Linux implementation of UDP?

Comment: For what purpose? You probably don't need it as much as you think. There's an enormous amount of TCP/IP source code in W.R. Stevens, *TCP/IP Illustrated,* volume II.

Comment: In the Linux kernel source tree?

Answer (score 2):

In the [kernel source](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/) of course:

- [UDP over IPv4](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/net/ipv4/udp.c)
- [UDP over IPv6](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/net/ipv6/udp.c)

Answer (score 0):

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/udp.7.html

further reading as an example of a server

http://linux.m2osw.com/c-implementation-udp-clientserver
and

http://www.linuxhowtos.org/C_C++/socket.htm